# 'context-path' error in Spring OXM

Tags: spring, marshalling, oxm

I have a Grails project that has a dependency, which is another project of mine, that uses `spring-oxm`. My Grails project can successfully `<import resource="some.xml">` the .xml located inside the .jar but it shows this error:

```
Attribute 'context-path' is not allowed to appear in element 'oxm:jaxb2-marshaller'
```

I have this dependency on my Grails BuildConfig.groovy:

```
    compile ('org.springframework:spring-oxm:3.1.0.RELEASE')
```

and this dependency on my other (Maven) project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is how I created the bean for the oxm-marshaller:

```
<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
     <property name="contextPath" value="com.somepackage.commons"/>
</bean>
```

Also, whenever I run my Maven project's tests, the spring application context loads perfectly which is why I'm sure that it works standalone.

What is the problem here? I've used the same spring-oxm dependency in both my projects, why do I still encounter these errors? Need help!

EDIT: Quick workaround... instead of importing my Maven project as a dependency, I tried copy-pasting all the code I had from my Maven project to the Grails project and it works just fine... still want to know what went wrong here :(

EDIT 2: I tried creating the bean in a different way... Instead of creating a Spring bean itself, I used the oxm namespace. When I created the marshaller in my Maven project it looked like this:

```
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" context-path="com.somepackage.commons"/>
```

What's funny was is that in my Grails project (the one I copy pasted earlier), it looked like this:

```
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" contextPath="com.somepackage.commons"/>
```

Notice the camelCase convention of the contextPath attribute. Why is it like this?

Comment: I found the same behavior.  In fact, Spring Tool Suite's xml editor complains "contextPath" is invalid but Maven won't compile unless it camelCased. I haven't investigated where the two diverge and why yet.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the actual spring oxm jar in the classpath points to the right xsd.
You will find the pointer in the the META-INF/spring.schemas file.  The “context-path” attribute is not defined in spring-oxm-3.x.xsd. It is defined in spring-oxm-4.x.xsd